# Android studio maven support removed?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I have my Android project with maven build, I used to import it into Android Studio by chosing "**maven**" as build tool in the window I am showing below, Android studio then automatically recognize my modules in POM, everything works well.

Today, I updated my Android Studio to the latest version 2.1.2 :

[image]

Then, I click "Import project(Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc)" like I used to do. Then in the following window:
[image]

Before I update my Android studio, there was an option "**Maven**" listed in this window, now, there is only "**Gradle**" , looks like after the update I'm not able to import maven project into Android Studio anymore...

Does anyone know how to have Maven support back with the latest Android Studio now?

Comment: Have you figured out a workaround to this?